# Php Autoresize image, image autoresized, but not saved in folder as resized image

Tags: php, html, mysql

after autoresize the image.....i have to move the image into folder, am getting resized image correctly into php variable but not able move into folder here is my code

```
    $ename=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $etype=$_FILES['userfile']['type'];
    $ecname=str_replace(" ","_",$ename);

    $tmp_name=isset($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
    $target_path="nurse_photo/";
    $target_path=$target_path.basename($ecname);

    $imgData=imagecrop($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['userfile']['name'],$_FILES['userfile']['type'],85,85);
    //echo $imgData;



    if(move_uploaded_file($imgData,$target_path))
    {
                 //insert query
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

move_uploaded_file() implies that first argument is filename, ie. $tmp_name is right choice for it.

I don't know what imagecrop() is. It's not PHP internal, but I suppose that is sort of GD processing. You should clear what $imgData type is! If it is image **body**, do

```
file_put_contents($target_path, $image);
```

But if it's GD image **resource**, do

```
imagejpeg($image, $target_path);
```

Comment: +1, Also want to add that move_uploaded_file() is not just check that argument is valid file name but also check for valid uploaded file through php POST. So in this case only variable $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] or $tmp_name will work for file path.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of image that's being uploaded, you could use functions like `imagejpeg`

Example:

```
$imgData = imagecrop($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['userfile']['name'], $_FILES['userfile']['type'], 85, 85);
// If $imgData is a jpg/jpeg:
imagejpeg($imgData, "/path/to/save/image", "9"); // Where the last arguement (9, in my case), is the image quality.
```

This will save the image to the desired path that you set in the function.

Of course, there are also `imagepng`, `imagegif`, and others.

Comment: if am giving echo $imgdata mean resized image is displayed correctly after i add imagejpeg($imgData, "photo/", "9") its not storing

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["pic"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["pic"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["pic"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["pic"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["pic"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["pic"]["size"] < 2097152)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{

if ($_FILES["pic"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["pic"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{

if ($_FILES["pic"]["size"] > 2097152) { // if file is larger than we want to allow
echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 2MB in file size.";
}
if (file_exists("Image/" . $_FILES["pic"]["name"]))
{
echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Picture Already Exists..!');</script>"; 

//echo $_FILES["pic"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"],"Image/" . $_FILES["pic"]["name"]);
//echo "your photo has been uploaded successfully!";
$abc = $_FILES["pic"]["name"];
}
}
}
```

use this code this sure solve ur prob.